# Pytest pass commandline arguments to tests even if argument is not defined in conftest

Tags: python, pytest

In pytest, the standard convention for passing cmdline args to tests is to add an option using `parser.addoption`  and define a fixture with the same name using `@pytest.fixture()`.

Example:

```py
# In conftest.py:

import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--input1", action="store", default="default input1")

@pytest.fixture
def input1(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--input1")
```

For this reason, our `conftest.py` has become pretty huge (*think AWS CLI*). I was wondering if, instead of defining each option explicitly in `conftest.py`, there is a way to parameterize and pass all command line arguments to the tests? Kind of like `*kwargs`

As per documents, pytest uses `argparse` which provides [parse_known_args](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#_pytest.config.argparsing.Parser.parse_known_args) function which outputs both known and unknown options. So technically this should be possible right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you still have to register each option in `pytest_addoption`, but you can access all options by using a single fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def options(request):
    yield request.config.option
```

This will provide the options namespace, and you can access each option using the dot notation:

```py
def test_something(options):
    print(options.input1)
```

(provided you have added the option `input1` as shown in your question)

The name of the option is either the name you provided using the `dest` argument in `addoption`, or derived from option name itself if `dest` is not given (by stripping the starting hyphens, and converting other characters not allowed in a variable name into underscores).

This behaves very similar to `argparse.parse_known_args`, as it also returns a namespace with all options. Note that the namespace will additionally contain a number of other options from `pytest` and `pytest` plugins.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I checked the pytest argparsing code and they definitely do not accept any un-defined parameters.

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/1ba5b485650d6f4ef8ef1ab6e2f782e2cf315ca8/src/_pytest/config/argparsing.py#L425-L431